# Setting up and displaying many-to-many relationships with CartoDB

Tags: carto, many-to-many

I have to display many-to-many relationships between offices and sub-offices for a client. Each office manages many sub-offices, each sub-office can be managed by many offices. The client is requesting the work to be done in CartoDB's online platform so they can easily make changes to it if necessary.

What I'd like to do is create a boundary line, with each office's coordinates as the centrum point, and the line to go around each sub-office. I'll use this to show overlaps.

It's been a few years since I've used any GIS software, and when I did it was QGIS or ArcGIS, mostly through the GUI. Conceptually I'm not sure where to get started. At the moment I have two data files, offices with coordinates, name, and sub-offices covered, and sub-offices with coordinates and names.

Answer (score 1):

At this moment to do this analysis you need to understand SQL language and leverage new Data Services API, probably this [routing function with waypoints](https://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-platform/dataservices-api/routing-functions/#cdbroutewithwaypointswaypoints-geometrypoint-mode-text-options-text-units-text) may be good enough but it's not solving the [Travelling Salesman Problem](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Travelling_salesman_problem) so you will have to get the order of your waypoints.